# Using high charts' 'rows' property from the 'data' module

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[Here is the relevant high charts api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.rows).  High charts has this great [js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/rows/) to show how using the `rows` property works.

The issue I am having is when I only want to grab selected data from a table whose rows are dynamically generated.

The strategy I foresee using is for each row of data I want, to assign it a class, grab it, and then push the data into an array which is inside that `rows` property.

I think I am grabbing the data ok. I think the issue is the syntax from my code is not matching up correctly to how the `rows` property wants it.

[My js fiddle attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/favLqs50/1/). If I can get that example to work then I should be good.

Here is how the highcharts api demo for `rows` shows the syntax:

```
data: {
  rows: [
    [null, 'Ola', 'Kari'], // series names
    ['Apples', 1, 5], // category and values
    ['Pears', 4, 4], // category and values
    ['Oranges', 3, 2] // category and values
  ]
}
```

And here is how I am attempting to grab the rows I want:

```
data: {
  rows: [
    [null, 'Names' ],
    /* Section that is not working 
     * Don't know how to make it match the high charts syntax */
    $('.the_name').each(function() {
      var ary = [];
      ary.push($this).text();
      ary.push(($this).closest(".the_count").text()); 
    });
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
var rows = [[null, 'Names' ]];
$('.the_name').each(function() {
               var ary = [];
               ary.push($(this).text());
               ary.push($(this).parent().children(".the_count").text()); 
                rows.push(ary);

            });
```

Now, replace the row attribute in chart to calculated row array.

http://jsfiddle.net/favLqs50/2/